# Mongodb Exporter doesn't Show the Metrics Using Docker and Prometheus

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile, monitoring, prometheus

I'm trying to dockerize mongodb monitoring from the tutorial I have seen in [this page](https://medium.com/@journald/prometheus-on-ecs-with-mongodb-exporter-8b58dad1ee8f).

Here is my Dockerfile configuration:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add wget && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN wget https://github.com/dcu/mongodb_exporter/releases/download/v1.0.0/mongodb_exporter-linux-amd64
RUN chmod 777 mongodb_exporter-linux-amd64
EXPOSE 9001
```

Prometheus.yml:

```
global:
    scrape_interval: 15s
    external_labels:
        monitor: 'my-monitor'
scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'mongodb-exporter'
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['mongodb-exporter:9001']
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services: 
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    environment: 
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - /home/mostafa/Desktop/docker_lab/mongo/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command: 
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'

  mongodb-exporter:
    build: .
    command: ./mongodb_exporter-linux-amd64 -logtostderr -mongodb.uri mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017 -groups.enabled 'asserts,durability,background_flusshing,connections,extra_info,global_lock,index_counters,network,op_counters,op_counters_repl,memory,locks,metrics'
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 9001:9001
```

> 1 mongodb_collector.go:70] Collecting Oplog Status
>
> 1 oplog_status.go:127] Failed to get local.oplog_rs collection stats.

The metrics I should see is [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*H0l126osHJkqbC-2pCDfyw.png) but now I just see the following metrics.

[image: My Metrics]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong IP/hostname when running the mongodb_exporter.

Instead of `127.0.0.1`, try using the name of the container of your Mongo DB as you have in the docker-compose.yml file, in your case it's `mongo`.

The full URI should be: `mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017`

Regarding the `Failed to get local.oplog_rs collection stats.` error, you need to give proper permissions to the user account that you use to scrape the DB, see details [in this blog post](https://stuff.21zoo.com/posts/prometheus-mongodb-exporter-user-permissions/).

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post. It still doesn't show the metrics!

Comment: Amended the answer to cover the `Failed to get local.oplog_rs collection stats` issue as well.